# Determining if a symmetric matrix is neither positive nor negative semi definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given any matrix A, how can I determine whether the following system is neither positive semi definite nor negative semi definite?

\begin{pmatrix}
        I & A \\
        A^T & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, you can use the [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness)

One can easily show that for 
$$X=
\begin{pmatrix}
        A & B \\
        B^T & C \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
 $X$ is positive (semi-)definite if and only if both  $A$ and $S$ are positive (semi-)definite where $S=C-B^TAB^{-1}$ is the Schur complement.

In your case,
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
        I & A \\
        A^T & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

and $S=-A^TA^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks!  Does the same logic hold for the negative case? (ie, X is negative semidefinite only iff both A and S are negative semidefinite?)

Comment: @Theo Yes. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118053/schur-complement-and-negative-definite-matrices